# Moving points along road line to generate start and end points 200 meters on either side of original point using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, network, route

I tried to keep it succinct in the title, but here is basically what I'm trying to do (I eventually need to script this using Python):

- Generate a start point 200m in one direction from the bridge point
- Generate an end point 200m in the other direction from the bridge point
- Use the bridge point as a barrier in the "Find Routes" analysis from start point to end point

I have access to ArcGIS routing services, spatial analyst, etc., and I'm working in ArcGIS Pro 2.8. Right now, I'm trying to hack it using select nearest road from a local road dataset (not a network), but the bridge points don't always end up exactly on those lines.

Comment: There are some functions of the `Geometry` class in arcpy that can be used to do this (see:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/geometry.htm ).  Eg, measure the distance along the line of an existing point using `measureOnLine()`, then add/substract 200m from this distance to get the distance for the new point(s) along the line and create their geometry with  `positionAlongLine()`.  If you want more help, you may need to post what you've tried, and details of what went wrong, or where you got stuck.